# Function to deep copy an Expression tree, including its parent hierarchy?

Tags: java, recursion, tree, expression, abstract-syntax-tree

I want to deep copy an expression tree. I know the traditional way of doing it which works for the most part. Heres the basic version of the Expression tree:

```
public class Expression {
    public Expression left;
    public Expression right;
    public Expression parent;
    public String middle;

    public Expression(Expression left, String middle, Expression right) {
        this.left = left;
        this.right = right;
        this.middle = middle;

        if (left != null) {
            left.parent = this;
        }

        if (right != null) {
            right.parent = this;
        }
    }

    public void setLeft(Expression left) {
        this.left = left;
        if (left != null) {
            left.parent = this;
        }
    }

    public void setRight(Expression right) {
        this.right = right;
        if (right != null) {
             right.parent = this;
        }
    }}
```

Here's the traditional way of deep copying:

```
public Expression copy() {
    Expression leftCopy = (left != null) ? left.copy() : null;
    Expression rightCopy = (right != null) ? right.copy() : null;
    
    return new Expression(leftCopy, operator, rightCopy, null);
}
```

Now this works nicely but I want another deep copy function (copyFull) which copies the parent hierarchy as well. The current deep copy only copies the expression and makes it the root regardless of if it was actually the root or not. Now how would I go about making a full deep copy function which would make sure the entire structure is copied including the parent hierarchy AND the function should return the copy of the expression instance which called the copyFull() function. I am fairly certain that this new deep copy function would make use of the previous one. Example usage:
`Expression rightRightCopy = originalExpression.right.right.copyFull();`
`Expression originalExpressionCopy = rightRightCopy.parent.parent;`

Comment: Then just follow the parent nodes until the next parent node would be null. This means now you've go the top node. Then you can use your `copy()` algorithm on that top node. `Expression current = startNode; while(current != null && current.parent != null) {current = current.parent;} Expression topNode = current;`. Then run your copy: `Expression newTreeRoot = topNode.copy();`.  Easy as pie.

Comment: Why not model the expression as an immutable structure?

Comment: To expand on @ValerijDobler's comment, if it's immutable then you don't need a deep copy.  Is there any reason the tree is not immutable? Do you need to modify it after it's built?

Comment: @JayC667 Thats just copying the entire tree (i.e calling copy() on the root) I dont want that.  I want a function expression.copyFull() which copies this expression's children and its entire parent hierarchy up until the root. and then the function should return the expression. The way u did it, the result is the copy of the  entire tree and you lose access to the actual expression (which could one of tree's descendants OR the tree itself). I know what I am asking and this is more complex than perceived. And no, Expression shouldnt be immutable, i want to be able to change it.

Comment: I'm not clear on what you want. In the question, you said *"... make sure the entire structure is copied including the parent hierarchy"*. But, in a comment you seemed to say you don't want the entire tree copied.  Perhaps you could edit the question and include some examples.

Comment: @AliAman Yes, please tell us what you actually want copied. You've stated twice already that "method which copies this expression's children and its entire parent hierarchy up until the root". But what is the so-called "parent hierarchy"? From the code you gave us, each node has two leaves and max one parent, so there can be only one topmost parent, the root. So if you copy the root recursively (as you already do), you copy the whole structure, "and its entire parent hierarchy", case closed. If we miss something essential, please provide more code or a graph to clarify what exactly you mean.

Comment: I'm sorry that my wording wasn't clear in the question. I have updated it. Please have a look. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Well after playing around a little bit. I found the solution. I'm not sure if its the cleanest way of doing it, but it gets the job done.

```
public Expression copyFull() {
    return copyFull(this);
}

private Expression copyFull(Expression reference) {
    if (reference.isRoot()) return copy()

    Expression parent = reference.parent;
    Expression current = this == reference ? copy() : this;
    Expression newParent = null;

    if (reference.isLeftChildOf(parent)) {
        Expression rightCopy = parent.right != null? parent.right.copy() : null;
        newParent = new Expression(current, middle, rightCopy);
    } else {
        Expression leftCopy = parent.left != null? parent.left.copy() : null;
        newParent = new Expression(leftCopy, middle, current);
    }
    
    newParent.parent = newParent.copyFull(parent).parent;
    return current;
}
```